# When talking about painful events in their lives, why do most people smile?

Tags: social-psychology, pain

I  watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr10kEq-eu4&t=28s) recently, and a common reaction in almost all of the strangers was that they were smiling, while talking about the most painful things they were told in their lives. My question is, why is that?

Is it because they have accepted these events and have learned to move on, or do they act out this courage because they do not want to feel inferior socially? Could it be a psychological mechanism to cope up?

Comment: It's because of the circumstance under which they are being asked. If they were asked the same question in a familiar setting by a close friend, they most probably wouldn't be smiling.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the instinct to view every bad experience as a learning situation. Sure, you were devastated by your father's death, but the loss of a close family member made you a stronger person. After all, the final stage of grief (which isn't limited to people) is acceptance. It's an evolutionary trick to find useful sentiment withing tragedy.